# rvm install troubles

Tags: linux, rvm

I have next kind of trouble. Each try to install rvm on my local system causing next error:

```
$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   125  100   125    0     0      5      0  0:00:25  0:00:20  0:00:05   184
100   125  100   125    0     0      3      0  0:00:41  0:00:41 --:--:--     3Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /usr/local/rvm/archives/wayneeseguin-rvm-stable.tgz: Permission 
Warning: denied
  0  799k    0  2896    0     0     69      0  3:17:42  0:00:41  3:17:01  3880
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 2896)

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/tarball/stable'.
  curl returned status '23'.
```

How can I change installation directory from */usr/local/* to my *$HOME* dir? I tried to change script manually but its didn't bring me any success. Thx

Comment: Are you running that command as root?

Comment: if I running this script under root its all ok, and installing rvm to /usr/local was successfull, but I didn't want every time running commands under root or with sudo (like sudo gem ..., sudo rvm get ..., etc.)

Answer (score 1):

the rvm_path pointing to `/usr/local/rvm` is selected when installer is run as root (sudo, su) or when it's already set in `/etc/rvmrc` / `~/.rvmrc`, try removing those two files:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/rvmrc ~/.rvmrc
```

also make sure to relogin / open new shell and validate there is no `rvm_path` before installing again:

```
env | grep rvm
```

Comment: the same situation after full cleanup :( blah-blah ... curl returned status '23'

Comment: Thx everybody, after deep greping I found in **etc** directory next file: **/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh**. This file was set **rmv_path parameter** to **/usr/local/rvm**.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would try to install the files to `/usr/local/rvm` (that's done when running it as root or in `sudo`mode).
If it doesn't work as a regular (local install) user, try to download the script instead

```
 wget https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer
```

open it `vi rvm-installer` and modify the `rvm_path="/usr/local/rvm"` to something else and then run it `bash ./rvm-installer stable`.

But it should really not be necessary...Are you sure you're not logged in as root?

Comment: yes, I am sure, that I am not root (uid != 0). On my previous systems I have success experience with rvm (5 servers), but on my home desktop I get this trouble. Too sad

Comment: my current OS is Ubuntu 11.10. And I have read all internets (thx Obama), it wasn't anything helpful unfortunately

Comment: (not really answering the question... but) Peter: changing the `rvm_path` is not sufficient as the `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` that would be generated is also hard coded to `/usr/local/`. so this would also need to be changed.